# Flutter: Unable to get textfield value on first submission

Tags: flutter, dart, state, textfield

I have form inside page, which contains four different fields and one button.

I have a strange issue, here's what I'm doing:

1. fill up form
2. hit **Add** button `//variables are null`
3. if I hit **Add** button again, I've correct values

I thought, maybe some library or code is causing issue so I reduced code to narrow down,  now I've very simple code, only one field with `material.dart` import package. But the problem still exists. :(

What I've **Noticed:** Hitting **Add** button always return data from previous state than current.

**Example:**

1. Fill up form with value `1000`
2. Hit **Add** button `//prints null`
3. Update value to `2000`
4. Hit **Add** button `//prints 1000`
5. Update value to `3000`
6. Hit **Add** button `//prints 2000`
7. and so on....

Here is complete **code**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddFees extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _AddFees();
}

class _AddFees extends State<AddFees> {
  final addFeesFormKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final addFeesScaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  String _fees;

  TextFormField fees;

  RaisedButton addFee;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _submit() {
    final form = addFeesFormKey.currentState;

    if (form.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        print(_fees);
        form.save();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fees = TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      onSaved: (val) => _fees = val,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Fees'),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Fee cannot be empty';
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    );

    addFee = RaisedButton(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        _submit();
      },
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      child: Text('Add Payment',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24.0)),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      key: addFeesScaffoldKey,
      body: new Form(
        key: addFeesFormKey,
        child: Center(
            child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 25.0,
              ),
              fees,
              SizedBox(
                height: 15.0,
              ),
              addFee
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What is going on with this?

Comment: add onSaved method _fees = val in setState in build method

Comment: tried it like this `onSaved: (val) => setState(() => _fees = val),` but same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured that out and the solution was pretty simple.

**Solution:** Calling `form.save();` before trying to access `variables` solve the issue.

I've swapped two lines in `void _submit()` method to make it work, here is the **updated code**:

```
void _submit() {
  final form = addFeesFormKey.currentState;

  if (form.validate()) {
    setState(() {
      form.save(); //swapped
      print(_fees);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `_fees = val` inside a setState - see example:

```dart
fees = TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      onSaved: (val) => setState(() => _fees = val), // This is change
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Fees'),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Fee cannot be empty';
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    );
```

Comment: I've updated code, according to your answer but same issue. I've even run `flutter clean` and rebuild code but no luck. BTW, I'm using it same way for login form and it is working fine there.